# htaccess - add SameSite=Lax to all cookies if it doesn't have Strict or Lax already set

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Uhm... I've searched the entire web for a solution but it's nowhere to be found.

Here's what I want it to do:

**If cookies doesn't have SameSite set to Strict or Lax - set it to Lax.**

This is to get rid of SameSite None and unset.

This code set all cookies to Lax, but its not conditional as I want it to be:

`Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; SameSite=Lax"`

Comment: Are you attempting to _override_ a Set-Cookie response that has just (in this response) been set by your application? Or a cookie that might have been set in a previous response that is now being sent from the client?

Comment: @mrwhite Both, this is for securing WordPress and plugin default cookies that doesn't have SameSite set. But the code shouldn't touch a cookie that already are Lax or Strict.

Comment: Guess it would make more sense to do this using two directives. First, check if `SameSite` is present with a value already, and replace that if necessary. And second, a check if SameSite is not present at all, to add it in that case. And of course this only makes sense for the SetCookie responses to begin with; the Cookie header you get with the _requests_, doesn't contain any SameSite info to begin with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.